# Undefined reference to my own function in Meson project during linking

Tags: c++, meson-build

I have a Meson C++ project with the following layout:

```
├── include
│   ├── cxxopts.hpp
│   ├── json.hpp
│   ├── loguru
│   └── redis-cpp
├── meson.build
└── src
    ├── frame_utils
    │   ├── frame_utils.cpp
    │   ├── frame_utils.h
    │   └── meson.build
    ├── meson.build
    ├── source.cpp
```

The main `meson.build` file includes the following:

```
project(
  'test',
  'cpp',
  version : '0.1',
  default_options :
    ['warning_level=3', 'cpp_std=c++17']
)

compiler = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
all_deps = [
  dependency('threads'),
  compiler.find_library('dl', required : false),
  # additional deps filled by subdirectories
]

all_includes = [
  include_directories('include/redis-cpp'),
  include_directories('include/loguru'),
  include_directories('include')
]

# filled by subdirectories
source_files = []

subdir('src')
```

The one in `src` has the following code:

```
subdir('frame_utils')

exe = executable(
  'source',
  'source.cpp',
  install : false,
  include_directories : all_includes,
  dependencies : all_deps,
  link_with: frame_utils_lib
)
```

And the one in `frame_utils`:

```
all_includes += include_directories('.')

frame_utils_lib = static_library(
  'frame_utils',
  'frame_utils.cpp',
  install : false
)
```

The library is very simple, consisting of a namespace and one function:

```
#ifndef FRAME_UTILS_H
#define FRAME_UTILS_H

#include <cstdlib>

namespace frame_utils {
double timecode_to_ms(int64_t timestamp);
}

#endif
```

Now, in my `source.cpp` file I call a function from `frame_utils`, like so:

```
#include "frame_utils.h"

// ...

frame_utils::timecode_to_ms(video_frame.timestamp)
```

Here, `video_frame.timestamp` is an `int64_t`.

When I build the project, I get the following error from `ld`:

```
FAILED: src/source
c++  -o src/source src/source.p/source.cpp.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--start-group src/frame_utils/libframe_utils.a -pthread -ldl -Wl,--end-group
/usr/bin/ld: src/source.p/source.cpp.o: in function `...':
/builddir/../src/source.cpp:111: undefined reference to `frame_utils::timecode_to_ms(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /builddir/../src/source.cpp:112: undefined reference to `frame_utils::timecode_to_ms(long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Visual Studio Code is able to resolve the namespace and function name/signature correctly. What am I missing?

The library definitely exports that function:

```
$ nm builddir/src/frame_utils/libframe_utils.a

frame_utils.cpp.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z14timecode_to_msl
```

Also, when I copy the same function with the same signature (just without the namespace) into the `source.cpp` file, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error was with the definition of the function itself, in the `.cpp` file. It should be set up like this:

```
#include "frame_utils.h"

namespace frame_utils {
double timecode_to_ms(int64_t timestamp) {
  return (double)timestamp / 10000.0;
}
}
```

Earlier, it was like this:

```
#include "frame_utils.h"

using namespace frame_utils;

double timecode_to_ms(int64_t timestamp) {
  return (double)timestamp / 10000.0;
}
```

For some reason, VS Code was able to resolve the function, but the linker wasn't.